# Asp.net - Web.Config - Custom Errors

Tags: asp.net, custom-error-pages

How can I set 404 and other error pages using web.config? I have tried adding following block in web.config.

```
     <customErrors defaultRedirect="Forms/Errors/Page_404.aspx" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="servererror.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Forms/Errors/Page_404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

but still its showing default error page of IIS7. How to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it myself. We need to add another section in web.config like below to make it work in IIS 7 / 7.5. For IIS 6 the one works which I mentioned in my question

```
<system.webServer>
...
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
<remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
<remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
<remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
<error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
<error statusCode="403" path="/403.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
<error statusCode="500" path="/500.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />         
</httpErrors>
...
</system.webServer>
```

Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the system.webServer section of your Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the "~/" before paths:

```
 <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Forms/Errors/Page_404.aspx" mode="On">
<error statusCode="500" redirect="~/servererror.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/NoAccess.htm" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Forms/Errors/Page_404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: Let me correct my question, it works as it is, in Visual Studio's internal server but does not work when i run under IIS. any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a relative path there. Could that be the problem?

Try using Fiddler to see what page your browser is being redirected to.

Comment: Let me correct my question, it works as it is, in Visual Studio's internal server but does not work when i run under IIS. any specific reason?