# Custom error redirect on 404 code for non-aspx files

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, .net-2.0, custom-error-pages, http-error

I added to my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Pages/Error/Error.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Pages/Error/Error404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

and it works fine for .aspx pages.
When I try to type: `http://domainname.com/notExist`, I get the default 404.

I tried the suggestions from:
[404 Redirecting for non aspx pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045733/404-redirecting-for-non-aspx-pages)

but nothing works for me.
Any ideas why?

I use .net 3.5, application pool pipeline mode is Integrated.

After adding `<httpErrors>` I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This, it will provide separate status. Then you can execute as per your requirement.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Pages/Error/Error.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Pages/Error/Error404.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
<system.webserver>
<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>    
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
          <error statusCode="401" path="/Pages/Error/Error.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
          <error statusCode="403" path="/Pages/Error/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
          <error statusCode="404" path="/Pages/Error/Error404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
          <error statusCode="500" path="/Pages/Error/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webserver>
```

Comment: I tried, but now I get 500 code (not custom as well :))

Comment: then do like this--><customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Pages/Error/Error.aspx"><error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Pages/Error/Error404.aspx"/><error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Pages/Error/Error.aspx"/></customErrors>

Comment: That's what I did... look at my question. Works only for .aspx files.

Comment: where is this in yr question? --> <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Pages/Error/Error.aspx"/> under <customErrors...

Comment: @Inbal Try --> <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Pages/Error/Error.aspx" >

Comment: @Inbal i hope u will get ans --> http://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-custom-httperrors.aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939371/asp-net-web-config-custom-errors

Comment: @Inbal you will find best answer here --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score -2):

You need to separate setting for other pages.

Try something like this.

```
 <system.webserver>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
             <error statusCode="404" path="~/Pages/Error/Error404.aspx" />
      </httpErrors>
 </system.webserver>
```

Comment: I already tried, but it doesn't work. I don't get my custom page.

Comment: did you putted both separately?

Comment: what do you mean by "both"? system.web and system.webserver settings?

Comment: Yes you should have both

Comment: Yes, I get 404, but I don't get my custom page

Comment: I added screen shot to my post

Comment: try some thing like this.  <error statusCode="404" path="~/Pages/Error/Error404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />