# Custom error page content not displayed properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-error-pages

I specified custom error page in web.config like this

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/Error.html" />
</system.web>
```

The custom error page and its content is displayed properly. but when the url ends with slash, the error page content is displayed and is not displayed properly.

For example:
www.abc.com/product         -> error page content is displayed properly 
www.abc.com/product/       ->error page content is not displayed properly

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

When the url ends with any other special characters other than "/", the url redirects correctly to Error.html, but the url ending with "/" is considered as project folder and so the error page is not displayed properly. Correct me if I am wrong.
Any suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you change your default redirect to `~/Error.html`?

Comment: It redirects to Error.html correctly. But when the url ends with forwardslash "/" the error page content is not displayed clearly

Comment: It looks like you want any attempt at "directory browsing" to redirect to your error page.  I'm not sure if this is possible without registering routes, as would be done with an MVC site.  You are still able to register routes in a normal ASP.NET site, but you'll have to setup IIS such that all requests are handled by `aspnet_isapi.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

You are wanting to redirect to your error page when a user attempts directory browsing.  This is generally an HTTP error, handled by the server, which is handled apart from your ASP.NET processing.

If you are using IIS7+, then you can take the solutions together from [How to disable Directory Browse in Web.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549374/how-to-disable-directory-browse-in-web-config) and [Asp.net - Web.Config - Custom Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939371/asp-net-web-config-custom-errors)

Specific to your case, you would want a block in your `web.config` similar to:

```
<system.webServer>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="403"/>
    <error statusCode="403" path="~/Error.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error"></customErrors>
```

and have in your View -> Shared Folder a View with the name "Error.cshtml"

In the View Error.cshtml add this line at the top:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

...your code.....
```

hope this helps

Comment: I am not trying in MVC. its a normal asp.net project